# How do I set the Facebook canvas to 'fluid'?

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I'm making a page for my Facebook page, and I'd like it to be as wide as possible.  I've created an app which pulls in the content, and have it set up both as an 'App on Facebook' and a 'Page Tab' (I wasn't sure which of those to use, so if anyone can advise me, I'd be grateful).

I've added the Page Tab to my Page, so it appears on the list in the left - it's pulling in the content from my site, which is great.

However, I can't get it to go wide.  I've read quite a few things which say I need to set the canvas to 'fluid' under advanced settings (e.g. http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/549/) - but I can't find advanced settings for my app!  Under 'settings' I just get the basic options.

Has the canvas been removed, am I looking in the wrong place for the setting, or do I need to do something else to enable the advanced settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/**Your AppId**/advanced - Then scroll to the bottom.